# Characters in Correct Position Without Array Java

Tags: java, string, random

I'm writing java code for a Mastermind type game where instead of colors, the computer generates a random 4 digit number for the player to solve. If the guess is incorrect, it is supposed to indicate what numbers of the guess were in the correct position of the random number generated. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.String;

public class CSCD210HW2
{
   public static final int MAX = 10;
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      int nums, guess, countMe;
      String userChoice;
      boolean tryAgain = false;
      boolean reDo = false;
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random rand = new Random();
      String ans = null;
      do
      {
         reDo = false;
         nums = rand.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
         countMe=0;
         do
         {
         System.out.print("Enter Four Digit Guess: ");
         guess = kb.nextInt();
         countMe++;
         while(guess < 1000 || guess > 9999)
         {
            System.out.print("I SAID 4 DIGITS! Try Again: ");
            guess = kb.nextInt();

         }
         if(nums < guess)
         {
            System.out.println("Your Guess Was Too High.");
            System.out.println("Guesses Left: "+(MAX-countMe));

         }

         else if(nums > guess)
         {
            System.out.println("Your Guess Was Too Low.");
            System.out.println("Guesses Left: "+(MAX-countMe));


         }
         if(nums == guess)
         {
            System.out.print("Congratulations! Computer Bust!");

         }

      }while(guess != nums && countMe < MAX);
      System.out.println(" Game Over! The Number Was: "+nums);
      System.out.print("Try Again? ");
      userChoice = kb.next();
      while(!userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
      {
         System.out.print("It's Quite Simple. YES or NO: ");
         userChoice = kb.next();
      }
      if(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"))
      {
         reDo = true;
      }
      }while(reDo);
   }//end main
}//end TheClass
```

My only problem is the numbers in the correct position part. I know it can be accomplished using an array, but I'm not comfortable using those yet, so I'd rather not. How else can I get this done?

Comment: You are going to have a much easier time using an array for this, and you'll benefit from learning more about an extremely important data structure.

If you're dead-set on avoiding arrays, you could convert the number to a 4-character string and then check elements in the string based upon position. But this approach is conceptually similar to dealing with an array anyway!

Answer (score 0):

A crude and simple check like this will work:

```
if ((nums / 1000) == (guess / 1000)) System.out.print("Num 1 matches");
if (((nums % 1000) / 100) == ((guess % 1000) / 100)) System.out.print("Num 2 matches");
if (((nums % 100) / 10) == ((guess % 100) / 10)) System.out.print("Num 3 matches");
if ((nums % 10) == (guess % 10)) System.out.print("Num 4 matches");
```

Obvisouly this is ugly-ish and can be done much nicer, but it illustrates the point. Integer division trims the remainder, so `1234 / 1000` gives you `1`. Modulo (`%`) gives you the remainder (so `1234 % 1000` results in `234`). Combining these two, you can get the single integer at each position in `nums` and `guess` and compare them.